# DataGridTemplateColumn combobox with Enum is updating all the rows with same value

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, combobox, datagrid

I am setting the `ObjectDataProvider` for the `Enum` like below

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EnumProvider" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:Mode"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources >
```

```
public enum Mode
    {
        ModeSlow = 0,
        ModeFast = 1,
        ModeNeutral = 2,
        ModeNone = 3
    }
```

Here is the `DataGrid` that displays the `Enum` values as `ComboBox`es

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridView" Grid.Row="0" DataGridCell.Selected="DataGridGotFocus" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding VariedObjectList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="true" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header=" ModeType " >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumProvider}}" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Path= ModeType, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <!-- Other columns ---->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

With ModeType being `Enum`, when a new row is entered, by default I want it to display 'ModeSlow' but its empty. Also, if I update one row, all the previous rows are also updated with the latest value. At times, if I update to `ModeFast`, it automatically changes to `ModeSlow`. Its behaviour is unpredictable. What am i missing here?. Please, guide.

```cs
public class VariedObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Mode modeType = Mode.ModeSlow;
    public Mode ModeType
    {
      get { return modeType ; }
      set
      {
         modeType = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("ModeType");
      }
     }
    private int val;
    public int Value {
            get { return val; }
            set
            {
                val = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
                SetValueRangeList();
            }
        }
    public List<strings> ValueRange { get; set; } 
    public string SelectedValueRange {get; set;}
}
```

in my xaml.cs. (Sorry, i made a typo , i'm actually binding to VariedObjectList  which is list of VariedObject )

```
private List<VariedObject> variedObjectList = List<VariedObject>();

public List<VariedObject> VariedObjectList {
            get { return variedObjectList ; }
            set
            {
                variedObjectList = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("VariedObjectList ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: How is the `VariedObjectList` *property* that you bind to defined in the view model?

Comment: @mm8: I edited the code to show that. VariedObjectList is List<VariedObject>.

Comment: @mm8 - Can i please get some pointers here? I'm struggling as it always set to default value and then only on 2nd attempt i can get my value set but once i again add new entry, it automatically takes last set value. i see my SelectedItem is syncing up wit last set value but even after setting IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=false it fails to work properly.

Comment: Your enum seems to be called `Mode` in your code but `Modes` in your XAML. What's the difference?

Comment: @mm8 I see that as typo again. Fixed it

Comment: @mm8: If when new row is added, if it shows the default value for enum then i think that should fix the problem. but it randomly shows the default value on new row added.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataGrid` is binded to a `VariedObjectList` object, which is not a list itself (despite the name).
The columns will search for properties binding in their `DataContext` that is set by the `DataGrid`. Each item in the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` collection will be the `DataContext` of a row.

Since `VariedObjectList` is not a list all the rows will have the same `DataContext`, and accordingly the same binded object, `VariedObjectList.ModeType`.

Just to clarify, the solution is to provide an actual collection to the `DataGrid`.

I hope I have been helpful.

Comment: VariedObjectList is actually List<VariedObject>. I edited the code as it was typo.

Comment: Small thing, you've set the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` binding as `Mode=TwoWay`, but `VariedObject.ModeType` does not notify its change. I don't think it's related to the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you bind a Selector (ComboBox) to an ObjectDataProvider the the Selector's IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property is automatically defaulted to true - which means that all selectors that use that ObjectDataProvider will have their SelectedItem value synchronised. Try this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumProvider}}" 
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=false .......
```

Comment: I tried this but still same problem. When new row is added, initially my ModeType is empty. Sometimes double clicking on the new row (in one of the property box), automatically displays the default value. Now if i edit to change then all is well. But in case when new row is added but default value is empty, now i set it to another value and then go on to edit other properties, ModeType changes to default ModeSlow. I then will have to set them again. this is really wierd. I believe if i get to display the default value, all this will be resolved. any other way to solve this ?